# How close did the landed first stage of the Falcon 9 get to the X on the landing pad?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing, reuse

The pad at Landing Zone 1 (Former LC-13 at Cape Canaveral) has a big giant SpaceX logo consisting of a stylized X.

SpaceNews reposted this picture of a guy on the X marks the spot, as distributed by SpaceX.

[image]

How close did the landed first stage, on Dec 21, 2015 (Orbcomm OG2 mission) come to the X?

This is relevant, since the X on the ASDS barges is a smaller space so accuracy in hitting the target matters.

[image]

On the NasaSpaceflight.com forums, there is a running Barge Landing Bingo thread, where the have divided the surface of the ASDS into a grid, and allowed people to pick grid coordinates to predict where the first landed stage will touch down. It looks like the LZ-1 landing was sufficiently unexpected that the LZ-1 Landing Bingo did not happen.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know how precise an answer you're looking for, but looking at this frame from the [helicopter video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCBE8ocOkAQ), it looks to me like it came down within one stage diameter of the center of the X:

[image]

Combined with the accuracy of the two failed barge landings, I assume this is not a fluke, and the stage can land this accurately on a regular basis.

---

As far as I know, the Jason-3 mission barge landing is the first time SpaceX has announced their landing accuracy, in this case within an impressive 1.3 meters (~4 feet) of dead center of the target.

---

Here's a picture looking down the first stage of the Thaicom-8 mission after landing. If the landing leg span is 18 meters, the rocket looks to be around 3 meters off center. This was a "hot and fast" landing from a geosynchronous launch mission.

[image]

---

Musk claimed an [0.7m off-target distance](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/900951975671373824) for the FORMOSAT-5 flight.

Comment: Hitting a barge in the middle of the Atlantic from almost orbital height is pretty darn accurate to a first approximation.  I saw that photo, I am curious for actual numbers.  There is a shot in one of Elon's videos that suggests it is on one of the legs of the X.

Answer (score 3):

From [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIzLMjiyBog) of LC1, the answer is revealed. 10 feet (3m) away from dead center is the answer.